# In Outlook 2013 (Windows 8.1) on receiving RSS messages, how do I add a rule to execute a script?

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-outlook, script, rss, rules

In Microsoft Outlook 2013 under Windows 8.1 I have various rules which execute several VBA scripts.

For this I have:

```
Files → Options → Trust Center → Macrosettings → Activate all macros
```

And also the registry entry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Security
DWORD: EnableUnsafeClientMailRules
Value: 1
```

Now I want incoming RSS feeds to trigger the execution of a script as well, but I can't make it work. (I am sure, that this had worked a while ago (2 years?), but that was on a different computer, to which I have no access any more. Possible Microsoft "security update" once again?)

Anyway, to add RSS feeds, I used

```
Files → Account settings → RSS Feeds → New
```

One such feed is

```
http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_europe.rss
```

The feeds work nicely, and messages are obtained as desired. By default, they go into an automatically created folder beneath my mail account on the left hand pane:

```
myname@mydomain.com
    ...
    RSS feeds
        ...
        CNN Europe
```

Now to create a rule, I use the blank rule template to create a rule for messages received by me.

In there is a selectable condition "from arbitrary RSS feeds". I select it, and on the next page I select "execute a script". I select the intended script and finish the rule.

The feeds produce messages, but the script is never entered (I put a breakpoint on the first executable statement).

I tried to change the location into which the feeds go, by using an alternate destination, so as to make it appear as if the feeds are part of my inbox.

```
myname@mydomain.com
    Inbox
        ...
        RSS
            ...
            CNN Europe
```

To no avail: the rule simply does not execute.

Any hints?

Comment: Apparently a security update has disabled scripts. Check first if the setting to `EnableUnsafeClientMailRules` is still there or was somehow undone. You could also run the script directly via the [NewMail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/application-newmail-event-outlook) or [ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/items-itemadd-event-outlook) events, but it will need to be written in VBA.

Comment: I just checked, it is still there. But that must have been so, because its absence would not allow the appearance of the checkbox item to execute a VBA script. Remember, the VBA scripts applied onto emails just work fine and as expected. But I can not apply any VBA script on a folder obtaining RSS feeds. There is no error or so, the script is just not entered.

Comment: @harrymc, I use the `MailItem` object as in `Public Sub ScanRSSPost(Item As Outlook.MailItem)`. Should I use another object?

Comment: I have not done this myself, but I know that NewMail or ItemAdd are more often recommended in this case than MailItem.

Comment: @harrymc, you guided me into the right direction. If you make a proper answer out of it, I'd attribute the answer and the bounty to you. Solution: (1) `Sub ScanRSSPost(Item As Outlook.PostItem)`, but this won't appear in the rules list. To make it appear, replace `PostItem` by `MailItem` which works, then (2) build the rule (on any RSS post, execute script `ScanRSSPost`), then (3) go back to the script and replace `MailItem` by `PostItem` (Outlook won't complain), then COMMENT THAT PROCEDURE IN THE SCRIPT! Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Microsoft security update has in effect disabled rule scripts,
since Microsoft found it much easier to abolish them rather than tackle
the security holes. This means that `PostItem` scripts cannot even
be seen in the list when creating the rule.

Thus the remaining avenue is to use a VBA script with the
[NewMail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/application-newmail-event-outlook)
or
[ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/items-itemadd-event-outlook)
events which still work.

The poster reports this sneaky workaround as the solution which worked for him:

1. Create `MailItem` script:

   ```
   Sub ScanRSSPost(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
   ```
2. Build the rule as: On any RSS post, execute script ScanRSSPost.
3. Go back to the script and replace `MailItem` by `PostItem` (Outlook won't complain).